# Prove Using Induction: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1/k(k+1) = n/(n+1)$

Tags: induction

The task at hand is to prove using induction that the following proposition holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$P(n): \sum_{k=1}^{n}1/k(k+1) = n/(n+1)$$

Here is the proof I have thus far:

**Base Case:** $(n=1)$

LHS $= 1/1(1+1) = 1/(1+1) =$ RHS

i.e., both LHS and RHS are $1/2$.

So the base case is true.

**Step Case:** Assume the proposition holds $n=k$; then show that it holds for $n=k+1$.

$1/k(k+1) + 1/(k+1)(k+2)$

$= k/(k+1) + 1/(k+1)(k+2)$

$= k(k+2)/(k+1)(k+2)  +  1/(k+1)(k+2)$

$= k(k+2)+ 1/(k+1)(k+2)$

$= k^2 + 2k + 1$

$= (k + 1)^2 / (k+1) (k+2)$

$= (k+1)/(k+2)$

$= (k+1)/((k+1)+1)$

Is this the right way to do it?

If so, where could my proof be clearer?

If not, could you help me to find the error(s)?

Comment: Shouldn't you be taking a summation of terms on the left-hand side?

Comment: It is not true that $1/k(k+1)=n/n+1$, unless you forgot something there.

Comment: i think you forgot a sum

Comment: Please write your math in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: [$\LaTeX$ help.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Counter example  $1/27(27+1) \ne 32/(32+1)$.  What you wrote doesn't make any sense as k and n can each be anything.  And if you restrict k = n it's obviously false.

Comment: The base case is fine, the induction step is still very badly messed up (as written in the question) because you list only one term of the necessary sum instead of showing the entire sum, and you have mixed up the use of $k$ as an induction variable with the use of $k$ as an index of the summation. But the accepted answer is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the $\sum{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}}$

If so:
$$\sum_{1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}} = \sum_{1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k} -\frac{1}{k+1}} = \frac{n}{n+1}$$

But if you want induction:

Step: $$\sum_{1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \sum_{1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{n}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{n+1}{n+2}$$

Comment: yes 1/k(k+1) = n/n+1     , why do u have 1/k - 1/(k+1) = n/n+1 ?

Comment: @Clabbe as you can see : $\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}$,
consider first few parts of the sum:
$1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + ...$ , so we see that some parts destoy each other, so you've got : $1 - \frac{1}{n + 1} = \frac{n}{n + 1}$

Comment: is the induction step complete? is the question done here?

Comment: @Clabbe actually yes, it's better to write the base of induction but it's obviously and you could check it by yourself

Comment: yes! thank you!

Comment: @Clabbe no problem, my friend

Comment: sorry to bother you once again but which is the Inductive Hypothesis here?

Comment: @Paul suppose that $\sum{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}} = \frac{n}{n+1}$